# how to catch error in firestore when no internet

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I recently updated my app from firebase to firestore but stuck at offline persistance. I am using react-native-firebase to integrate firestore and disable its perisistance but still not getting any catch error when no internet.
This is my code to delete data but catch never gets error when no internet not is the promise resolved.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('d').doc(deviceid).delete().then(function () {
                                    console.log("Device Deleted");
                                    that.setState({
                                        loading: false
                                    });
                                    Toast.show('Device Deleted Succesfully', {
                                        duration: Toast.durations.SHORT,
                                        position: Toast.positions.TOP,
                                        shadow: true,
                                        animation: true,
                                        hideOnPress: true,
                                        delay: 0,
                                    });

                                }).catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    that.setState({
                                        loading: false
                                    });
                                })
```

Answer (score 21):

Firestore and Realtime Database SDKs don't throw errors when there is no network connectivity.  They will silently retry the connection in hopes that the device will regain network connectivity soon.  The reason for this is because most developers don't want their apps to appear broken just because the user went into a tunnel and back out, or switched between mobile towers in a way that forced a network reset.

In order to effectively make use of an online database, the device should be online most of the time, and this the situation that the SDK is optimizing for.

Comment: Thanks Doug for quick response. I want to delete a document only when device is online. As other people will be simultaneously using the same document. So is there any work around for this.

Comment: You could use Cloud Functions to define an HTTP function that you can call from the client that performs the work.

Comment: I thought of that but wont that be unnecessary as i can update firestore without calling an api.

Comment: Since methods like `get` return a promise and in a case the user is temporarily offline the promise `resolves`  even though the request failed while the sdk is silently retrying in the background. The issue is that the retry operation is cut off from the app state updating mechanism. It would make sense to keep the loading state displayed while retrying, however since the promise resolved long ago, how is the app going to recover. The only logical paths seems to be to either not resolve or reject the promise until the request succeeds or return an observable. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

Make your own helper function for deletion that throws an error if there is no Internet connection. You can make the API cleaner by not calling `.collection()` but rather passing the full path `d + deviceid` to it.

```
function onlineOnlyDelete(path) {
  if(!deviceApi.hasInternet()) throw 'No Internet, no delete'
  return firebase.firestore().doc(path).delete()
}
```

replace `firebase.firestore().collection('d').doc(deviceid)` with `onlineOnlyDelete(d+deviceid)` and you should be good to go

Comment: I like this method. Loose coupling with firebase yet can be as granular as one wants. It works very well with [`react-native-netinfo`](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo).

Answer (score 5):

Referencing this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/525). I set up the following check:

```
.then(() => {
  if (snapshot.empty && snapshot.metadata.fromCache) {
     throw new Error('Failed to fetch ideas');
  }
})
```

Then later on I caught the error and set the app state to include the error along with parameters specific to the batch like `startIndex` and `stopIndex` which will be important later. When rendering the documents, one case is reserved for the `BatchError` as I dubbed it, in which case the user is going to see a `Refetch` button which has a callback attached to it. Using the batch metadata, the callback is able to reinitialize the specific batch request.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a transaction that will actually throw an error if it's unsuccessful. It has timeout and maxAttempts parameters.