# How to setup a listener for Firebase connectivity in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to catch a 'No Network' error.

I'm listening to a document in Firestore like this:

```
final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(kInfoCollection).doc(kInfoDocument);

docSubscription = docRef.snapshots().distinct().listen((_) {});

docSubscription.onData((snapshot) => _processInfo(snapshot))

docSubscription.onError((e, s) {
        final errorMessage = 'Message:\n$e \nThe Stack was:\n$s';
        print('Error $errorMessage');
        throw InfoException(errorMessage);
      });
```

So as you can see, the listener is listening to a document and will throw an error if it catches any.

But these Firebase errors as shown in the console wasn't caught:

```
Connection 1: encountered error(1:53)
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (283fb4118) Stream error: 'Unavailable: Network connectivity changed'
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (283fb4118) Stream error: 'Unavailable: DNS resolution failed'
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (283fb4118) Stream error: 'Unavailable: DNS resolution failed'
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (283fb4118) Stream error: 'Unavailable: failed to connect to all addresses'
```

Am I missing something?

Additional info: I simulate this by going to Airplane mode on my phone. Otherwise there is no error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, unfortunately I don't have a solution yet. Hopefully someone will soon.

Comment: How come we got 8 upvote and no one from Firebase yet to answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin to discover network connectivity and catch these errors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

About this problem you might find this interesting: [how to catch error in firestore when no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543290/how-to-catch-error-in-firestore-when-no-internet)

It seems that this is a normal behavior to avoid breaking an app just because there is temporarily no connection.

I hope this will help you even if this question is 7 months old already.